# How should I parse this xml string in python?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

My XML string is -

```
xmlData = """<SMSResponse xmlns="http://example.com" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
             <Cancelled>false</Cancelled>
             <MessageID>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</MessageID>  
             <Queued>false</Queued>
             <SMSError>NoError</SMSError>
             <SMSIncomingMessages i:nil="true"/>
             <Sent>false</Sent>
             <SentDateTime>0001-01-01T00:00:00</SentDateTime>
             </SMSResponse>"""
```

I am trying to parse and get the values of tags - Cancelled, MessageId, SMSError, etc. I am using python's [Elementtree](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree) library. So far, I have tried things like -

```
root = ET.fromstring(xmlData)
print root.find('Sent')  // gives None
for child in root:
    print chil.find('MessageId') // also gives None
```

Although, I am able to print the tags with -

```
for child in root:
    print child.tag
    //child.tag for the tag Cancelled is - {http://example.com}Cancelled
```

and their respective values with -

```
for child in root:
    print child.text
```

How do I get something like -

```
print child.Queued // will print false
```

Like in PHP we can access them with the root -

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
$status = $xml->SMSError;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your document has a namespace on it, you need to include the namespace when searching:

```py
root = ET.fromstring(xmlData)
print root.find('{http://example.com}Sent',)
print root.find('{http://example.com}MessageID')
```

output:

```py
<Element '{http://example.com}Sent' at 0x1043e0690>
<Element '{http://example.com}MessageID' at 0x1043e0350>
```

The `find()` and `findall()` methods also take a namespace map; you can search for a arbitrary prefix, and the prefix will be looked up in that map, to save typing:

```py
nsmap = {'n': 'http://example.com'}
print root.find('n:Sent', namespaces=nsmap)
print root.find('n:MessageID', namespaces=nsmap)
```

Comment: so basically I am gonna have to specify "{http://example.com}" every time I want to access the text of a tag?

Comment: @HussainTamboli: There is also a `namespaces=mapping` argument to `find` and `findall` but that appears to be useless when there is a default namespace. `lxml` handles this all a lot better.

Comment: See @eclaird's answer. I think you were trying to do the same. +1

Comment: It still prints `None` with nsmap. I think there is something wrong with nsmap.

Comment: @HussainTamboli: I get output for your sample XML. Make sure you spelled the tag name correctly (`MessageID` and not `MessageId`).

Comment: I was using `xml.etree.ElementTree` from the [link](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree). I think you are using - `lxml.etree` like @root is using.

Comment: @HussainTamboli: No, I am using `xml.etree`, python 2.7. `lxml` supports the same API (albeit with some improvements, but this is the same in both).

Comment: @HussainTamboli -- Martijn's code is correct, you must have made a mistake somewhere. I wrote down the full code, that gives me a result, try copy-paste'ing it and see if it works.

Comment: hi, `root.find('n:Sent', namespaces=nsmap)` is printing the object. append `.text` to it.

Answer (score 3):

If you're set on Python standard XML libraries, you could use something like this:

```
root = ET.fromstring(xmlData)
namespace = 'http://example.com'

def query(tree, nodename):
    return tree.find('{{{ex}}}{nodename}'.format(ex=namespace, nodename=nodename))

queued = query(root, 'Queued')
print queued.text
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a dictionary and directly get values out of it...

```
tree = ET.fromstring(xmlData)

root = {}

for child in tree:
    root[child.tag.split("}")[1]] = child.text

print root["Queued"]
```

Comment: hi, see my edit. "//child.tag for the tag Cancelled is - {http://example.com}Cancelled" so it is difficult to match it with "Cancelled". Is there any better way?

Comment: Hey. it works but this is just an adjustment. How do I access the text of the tags in a way where tag is a key and text is the value.

Comment: Also you might wanna change the `return null` to `return None` or `return ''`. Because with null, it says - `NameError: global name 'null' is not defined`

Comment: This maybe an alternate solution too. +1

Comment: Updated answer with a neater one.

Answer (score 2):

With `lxml.etree`:

```
In [8]: import lxml.etree as et

In [9]: doc=et.fromstring(xmlData)

In [10]: ns={'n':'http://example.com'}

In [11]: doc.xpath('n:Queued/text()',namespaces=ns)
Out[11]: ['false']
```

With `elementtree` you can do:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET    
root=ET.fromstring(xmlData)    
ns={'n':'http://example.com'}
root.find('n:Queued',namespaces=ns).text
Out[13]: 'false'
```

Comment: thanks. I was wondering to find something similar in ElementTree. +1