# Get specific text from xml using python

Tags: python, xml

I have an XML string which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:geonode="http://www.geonode.org/" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.geonode.org/">
  <xsd:import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/gml/3.1.1/base/gml.xsd"/>
  <xsd:complexType name="test_24Type">
    <xsd:complexContent>
      <xsd:extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="attribute_1" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="the_geom" nillable="true" type="gml:MultiLineStringPropertyType"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:element name="test_24" substitutionGroup="gml:_Feature" type="geonode:test_24Type"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

What I want to do is to use Python in order to extract the url corresponding to xmlns:geonode:

```
"http://www.geonode.org/"
```

I know there is this library: from xml.etree import cElementTree as ET
But I am not sure how to use it properly in order to extract information which is on this element.

Answer (score -1):

The following is one of the ways to extract data from xml file using xml.etree library and python 2.7.
Replace the xml file name and the tag name in the corresponding places in the code.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as XT
dataTree = XT.parse('your_xml_file_name.xml')
dataRoot = dataTree.getroot()
geoNode = dataRoot.find('your_tag_name').text
print geoNode
```

Comment: Thanks. I do not have a file but a variable which the XML string is stored.

Comment: In that case you can use the variable name in the place of the file name. Please see these answers for more detailed solutions: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153988/how-should-i-parse-this-xml-string-in-python)

Comment: The question is about extracting `http://www.geonode.org/` from the `xmlns:geonode="http://www.geonode.org/"` namespace declaration. This code does not do that.